# Is there any tool that could turn a Petri Net into system of math equations?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I have a colored, descrete Petri Net. I have a picture. How to get a math (ODE\DE\system of equations) representation of it?

Answer (score 0):

i strongly recommend you to study murata article on petri nets which has a mathematical analysis approach on petri net. you will find a good mathematical analysis in that. below is its link:

[murata article on petri nets.](http://user.das.ufsc.br/~mvallim/rdp/murata_89_00024143.pdf)